# Making a continuous servo motor rotation clockwise but pauses (ticks) every 30 degrees

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I am creating a color sorting machine using SG90 continuous servo motor, but the sensor is 30 degrees clockwise, I need to pause for some time to allow the sensor to get the data needed from the object.

```
int servoIncrement = 30;  // Amount to increment the servo position
int pauseTime = 500;  // Pause time in milliseconds
int servoPosition = 0;  // Initial servo position

void setup() {
  pinMode(S0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(S3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorOut, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(S0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(S1, LOW);
  FeedingServo.attach(FeedingServoPin);
  DecisionServo.attach(DecisionServoPin);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
   FeedingServo.write(servoPosition);

  // Increment the servo position
  servoPosition += servoIncrement;



  // Pause for the specified time at each 30-degree position
  if (servoPosition % 30 == 0) {
    delay(pauseTime);
  }
  
  // Adjust the pause time based on your servo's speed if necessary

  // Delay before the next iteration
  delay(15);  // Adjust the delay time as per your requirement
}
```

I need it to pause (delay) for a certain time when the object is under the sensor.
I tried FeedingServo.write(88.999) to make it rotate at the slowest possible speed but still is too fast for the sensor to pick up data.